# How do I make the following into a short exact sequence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$0 \to \mathbb{Z_2}\to \mathbb{Z_4} \to \mathbb{Z_2} \to 0$?

I've tried defining $f: \mathbb{Z_2}\to \mathbb{Z_4}$ to be the inclusion map and $g:\mathbb{Z_4} \to \mathbb{Z_2}$ is defined as $ 0 \mapsto 0, 1 \mapsto0, \{2,3\} \mapsto 1$.

But then $g$ does not remain a homomorphism, and changing it to something else would mean ${im}(f)=\mathbb{Z_2} \not= ker(g)$.

Comment: The problem is that the "inclusion" $\mathbb Z_2 \to \mathbb Z_4$ is not a homomorphism either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the inclusion map $\imath:\Bbb Z_2\to\Bbb Z_4$ is not a homomorphism, as we have
$$\imath(1+1)=\imath(2)=\imath(0)=0\neq\imath(1)+\imath(1)=2$$
To make it exact you need the initial homomorphism being the multiplication of $2$, which I denote $m_2$, and you can have the last one being the inclusion, that is
$$0\to\Bbb Z_2\overset{m_2}{\to}\Bbb Z_4\overset{\imath}{\to}\Bbb Z_2\to 0$$
You can easily see both are homomorphisms and we have
$$\text{im }m_2=\{0,2\}$$
and
$$\ker\imath=\{0,2\}$$
and that they are injective nad surjective.

Answer (score 1):

The injective map is deduced from
\begin{align}
\pi\colon\mathbf Z  &\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z \\
1&\longmapsto 2+4\mathbf Z
\end{align}
The kernel is $2\mathbf Z$, so we obtain, by the first isomorphism theorem, an injective morphism
$$\mathbf Z/\ker\pi\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z.$$

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is not a homomorphism if it's the inclusion map.  We need $f(0) = f(1+1) = f(1) + f(1)$ since $1+1 = 0$ in $\Bbb{Z}_2$, but $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) + f(1) = 2 \ne 0$ in $\Bbb{Z}_4$.

Let $f$ be defined as $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 2$.  Then $f$ is a homomorphism and is clearly injective.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Any surjective homomorphism $\Phi: G \rightarrow H$ between two groups $G$ and $H$ gives rise to a short exact sequence: $$ 0 \rightarrow K \stackrel{\iota}{\hookrightarrow} G \stackrel{\Phi}{\rightarrow} H \rightarrow 0$$ where $K$ is the kernel of $\phi$ and $\iota$ the injection of $K$ into $G$. So in this case (with $a$ a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_4$) $\Phi: a \mapsto a^2$ and $K = \langle a^2 \rangle$.